# How to keep EXIF data in a DSLR video after editing / compressing with Photoshop CC?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, adobe-photoshop, compression

So I have a bunch of home video files with my kids and family.
I want to do some edits like text overlay, music backgrounds etc and also compress them using Photoshop CC.
However, after compressing or exporting the video file, the original EXIF is lost. I don't have the capture date and time, the camera & lens used etc.

How can I make Photoshop keep this information?
Or is there a way to copy the EXIF after the export?

I tried using ffmpeg, but it only copies the capture date and time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to copy tags from one file to another, eg:

```
exiftool -tagsFromFile original.mts newfile.mp4
```

Make sure you're using the latest version. Older versions can't write mp4 files.

Comment: Thanks Ben, that did the trick.
It only copied capture time and camera info, but not lens info. But it's good, it's something :)